# Can ReadWrite lock perform worse than conventional locks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, readwritelock

From [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html):

> Whether or not a read-write lock will improve performance over the use
> of a mutual exclusion lock depends on the frequency that the data is
> read compared to being modified, the duration of the read and write
> operations, and the contention for the data - that is, the number of
> threads that will try to read or write the data at the same time.

As a beginner, I need someone's help to help me clear some things. Text in quote makes sense, because in general why would we want **one reader thread** to wait for **another reader thread**? In this way, using `ReadWriteLock`, we can have *concurrency* in readers and not have *complete mutual exclusion* between every single thread.

So I thought, why not always use `ReadWriteLock` instead of `conventional` locks? No matter if I have little readers, there could come a situation when two readers try to access a shared resource at the same time. But that sounds too easy, plus why are those rules that tell me when to pick `ReadWrite` at all?

Can someone tell me what am I missing? In my opinion, I would always prefer `ReadWrite` against `conventional` locks, because although there could be little readers/not long operation/little thread contentions, there could still come a scenario where I could profit with that "little given concurrency" for readers.

Comment: A `ReadWriteLock` is more complex, so if you only ever use exclusive locks (i.e. the write lock), a simple lock will be (slightly) faster, and use less memory.

Comment: Yes, and I usually refer to this [article](http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/02/11/readerwriter-locks-and-their-lack-of-applicability-to-finegrained-synchronization/) to show that it isn't just a "Java thing". A r/w lock has to maintain the number of readers and avoid writer starvation, which results in management overhead. That can use shared atomics or even an exclusive lock. An exclusive lock will outperform for short critical sections, whereas a r/w lock can be beneficial when longer (e.g. I/O).

Comment: And you need to explicitly release ReadWrite lock in finally statements.